# Minimal iOS code to do an HTTP GET from Amazon S3 with authorization?

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, secret-key

The documentation for AWS (Amazon Web Services) is vast, and rather chaotic. I found a git repo for iOS that demonstrates performing various tasks including a couple of projects for getting/putting data to S3.

I already have an existing client application that uses Apples NSURLSession to do HTTPS GET requests for content from S3 when the records are public. However, my client want the data to be secure.

I don't want to invest the time to learn the AWSS3TransferManager framework, and I don't want to include the whole framework in my project, either). I don't want all that baggage. All I need is a call that will let me provide a user ID or access key/secret key, or perhaps a password, and get a query string I can add to my HTTP get requests that authorizes the request for all users of the app.

I don't need upload. I don't need API-based console support. I don't need or want Amazon's session manager/download manager. All I want is the 1 call that will let me provide an access key and secret key and get back something I can add to the get request that authorizes it, so I can submit a request and get back a file. Should be easy, right? I've been pouring through the documentation and sample code for a couple of hours now, and no luck.

Looking at the samples, they use 500 kilos of frameworks I don't need and don't want.

Can somebody point me to a minimal library that lets me generate the key(s) I need to prove that the user has access to this content, given username and an access key Id and secret key, or perhaps a password? This would not be that hard.

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple code for HTTP GET. If you are interested in HTTP PUT - check implementation at  http://simpleios.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com.

#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>

```
static NSString * const accessKey=@"AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE";
static NSString * const secretKey=@"wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY";
```

...

```
NSString * fileUrl=@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/someBucket/someFile";
NSString * bucket=@"someBucket";
NSString * filePath=@"someFile";

NSURLSession *delegateFreeSession=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue    mainQueue]];
[[delegateFreeSession dataTaskWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[fileUrl stringByAppendingString:[self buildQuery:bucket forFile:filePath]]] completionHandler:^(NSData *received, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
if(error!=nil ){
NSLog(@"Error trying to download file - %@", error);
}
else{
    //do something
}
}] resume ];

...

- (NSString * ) buildQuery:(NSString *)bucketName forFile:(NSString *)filePath{

NSString *expDate=[self expirationDate];

NSMutableString *base=[NSMutableString new];
[base appendString:@"?AWSAccessKeyId="];
[base appendString:accessKey];
[base appendString:@"&Expires="];
[base appendString:expDate];
[base appendString:@"&Signature="];

NSMutableString *stringToSign=[NSMutableString new];
[stringToSign appendString:@"GET\n\n\n" ];
[stringToSign appendString:expDate];
[stringToSign appendString:@"\n" ];
[stringToSign appendString:@"/"];
[stringToSign appendString:bucketName];
[stringToSign appendString:@"/"];
[stringToSign appendString:filePath];

NSString *signature=[self sign:stringToSign];
signature=[signature stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"%2F"];
signature=[signature stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
signature=[signature stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"%3D"];

[base appendString:signature];

return base;
}

- (NSString *) expirationDate{

int expireInSeconds=300;
double sec=[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]+expireInSeconds;
static NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter=nil;

if(numberFormatter==nil){
numberFormatter=[NSNumberFormatter new];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
}

NSString *expDate=[numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:sec]];

return expDate;
}

- (NSString *)sign:(NSString *)stringToSign {

NSData *data=[stringToSign dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
CCHmacContext context;
const char *keyCString = [secretKey cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
CCHmacInit(&context, kCCHmacAlgSHA1, keyCString, strlen(keyCString));
CCHmacUpdate(&context, [data bytes], [data length]);
unsigned char digestRaw[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
NSInteger digestLength = CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH;
CCHmacFinal(&context, digestRaw);
NSData *digestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:digestRaw length:digestLength];
return [digestData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem with this is that it sounds like you are trying to embed secret/access keys into the app itself instead of using something more secure like Amazon Cognito https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/, which the iOS SDK provides access to.

The other is that iOS SDK for AWS doesn't allow you to cherry pick which methods to include, though it does allow you to generate a pre-signed URL for S3 gets. For just S3 you only need the S3 & Core frameworks, but it sounds like that is too much as well.

If you really just want the most minimal download size possible you could implement AWS signing yourself by looking at the AWS iOS SDK source code https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios or S3's signing documentation, but signing an AWS request is non-trivial, and you would lose a lot of beneficial logic (retries, ect...).

You also mentioned not wanting to learn the TransferManager. The TransferUtility is the successor of that and would be drastically faster to learn than implementing your own signing. I can't see it taking more than an hour or two to understand it (maybe a little more if you decide to use Cognito for authentication, but that's really tangential to TransferUtility). http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transferutility.html

Edit: In order to give credentials for the PreSignedURLBuilder. You can also see adding credentials to all clients created with the SDK at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html (Getting started with Swift/Objective-c section)

You can use this to provide credentials

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc]
                                                      initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1 identityPoolId:@"IDENTITY_POOL_ID"];
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc]
                                          initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

[AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder registerS3PreSignedURLBuilderWithConfiguration:configuration
                                                                  forKey:@"customServiceConfiguration"];
 AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder *customPreSignedURLBuilder = [AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder S3PreSignedURLBuilderForKey:@"customServiceConfiguration"];
```

Comment: Based on what I read you can take your id and secret ID, the URL you are going to request, and a server timestamp, and generate a signature string that you can then embed as a query string in your request. That is ALL I need. However, the description is long, fussy, and quite involved, with lots of opportunities for small mistakes that would prevent it from working and require lots of debugging. Bleh.

Comment: I have an app that is fully written and fetches S3 records using public URLs. It uses the `NSURLSession`, and already handles background downloading, error recovery, etc. Apple is able to offer downloads that continue when your app has been terminated. A third party app can't do that unless their API is built on top of `NSURLSession` and creates a download task.

Comment: You said "...it does allow you to generate a pre-signed URL for S3 gets." By it, you mean the Amazon SDK? How? That's what I need to do, although I would prefer not to use a static URL that always works. In that case somebody can just get the URL and request it from a different device, thus defeating the security entirely.

Comment: If you checkout http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html and go to the section " Use Pre-Signed URLs to Transfer Objects in the Background " you will see how to use the SDK to create a pre-signed URL, which would allow you to use your apps controls to download the file. This still requires the S3/Core frameworks. If you have a server it would be more secure to request the URL from the server, and any language that has an AWS SDK can generate a presigned url for S3 and return it to your app.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Question: Where is the security if you use that framework to generate a pre-signed URL? It looks like it doesn't require your access key or secret to create that private URL. What's to stop somebody else from liking against the S3 and core frameworks and doing exactly the same call if it doesn't require credentials?

Comment: yesterday I was able to find the section of the AWS docs you linked to, but today, despite searching intensely for 45+ minutes, I can't find it again. Can you point me to a link to the section on "Use Pre-Signed URLs to Transfer Objects in the Background" for iOS? Yesterday I found help that included an incomplete code snippet. Now I can't find that.

Comment: To get a presigned URL for an object, you make a call to S3 (using your credentials). So you still need AWS credentials to get the URL, and the URL expires after a set amount of time you set. So you can create this URL from the server and send the URL to the app.

The link is still the same, please see my June 22nd comment. (click the link, don't copy/paste because SO cuts off long links, but if you click it is correct).

Comment: What S3 call do you make (with your credentials) to get back a signature? That's the bit I have not been able to find anywhere.

Comment: Updated answer to show credentials flow to create the PresignedURLBuilder